# ServiceStack CreatorKit migrations failing

Tags: github-actions, servicestack

I'm interested in setting up the CreatorKit project on a new Ubuntu server and I'm at a point where I'm running out of ideas for troubleshooting a Github Actions deploy issue.
The 'Run remote db migrations' is failing from the 'deploy_via_ssh' step in the release.yml workflow.

Based on what I'm seeing, this is the main error preventing the migration from completing:

```
ERROR: Could not find a part of the path '/CreatorKit.ServiceModel/Types/MailingList.cs'., Exception: Could not find a part of the path '/CreatorKit.ServiceModel/Types/MailingList.cs'.
```

I'm using the CreatorKit project from https://github.com/NetCoreApps/CreatorKit with sqlite as the db.

Additional errors are listed below. These represent about line 200+ in the 'Run remote db migrations' step:

```
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | 
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | 
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | ERROR: Could not find a part of the path '/CreatorKit.ServiceModel/Types/MailingList.cs'., Exception: Could not find a part of the path '/CreatorKit.ServiceModel/Types/MailingList.cs'.
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/CreatorKit.ServiceModel/Types/MailingList.cs'.
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at System.IO.Strategies.OSFileStreamStrategy..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at System.IO.Strategies.FileStreamHelpers.ChooseStrategy(FileStream fileStream, String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, Int64 preallocationSize)
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at System.IO.StreamWriter.ValidateArgsAndOpenPath(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize)
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents)
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at CreatorKit.Migrations.Migration1001.Up() in /app/CreatorKit/Migrations/Migration1001.cs:line 173
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at ServiceStack.OrmLite.Migrator.<>c.<Run>b__20_2(MigrationBase x) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Migrator.cs:line 194
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at ServiceStack.OrmLite.Migrator.Run(IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory, Type nextRun, Action`1 migrateAction, String namedConnection) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Migrator.cs:line 459
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | ERROR: Failed to run AppTask 'migrate', Exception: Could not find a part of the path '/CreatorKit.ServiceModel/Types/MailingList.cs'.
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '/CreatorKit.ServiceModel/Types/MailingList.cs'.
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at ServiceStack.OrmLite.Migrator.Run(Boolean throwIfError) in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Migrator.cs:line 234
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at ServiceStack.OrmLite.Migrator.Run() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Migrator.cs:line 137
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at CreatorKit.ConfigureDbMigrations.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__1(String[] _) in /app/CreatorKit/Configure.Db.Migrations.cs:line 16
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |    at ServiceStack.AppTasks.RanAsTask() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack.Common/AppTasks.cs:line 105
err: Aborting on container exit...
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1 exited with code 1
err:  Container deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  Stopping
err:  Container deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  Stopped
2023/08/13 23:32:21 Process exited with status 1
```

Running Github Actions using the identical code and yml files (and git commit), I also occasionally get Migration timeout errors. See below for an example.

```
err:  Container deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  Recreated
out: Attaching to deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | info: ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost[0]
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |       Initializing Application Creator Kit took 633.3751ms. No errors detected.
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | Running AppTask 'migrate'...
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | Migrations Found:
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |  - Migration1000
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |  - Migration1001
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  |  - Migration1002
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | 
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | ERROR: Migration 'Migration1001' is still in progress, timeout in 84.427s.
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | ERROR: Failed to run AppTask 'migrate', Exception: Migration 'Migration1001' is still in progress, timeout in 84.427s.
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  | Migration 'Migration1001' is still in progress, timeout in 84.427s.
err: Aborting on container exit...
out: deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1 exited with code 1
err:  Container deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  Stopping
err:  Container deploy-creatorkit-testing-migration-1  Stopped
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely because the empty `/Types` folder doesn't exist. I've just added a README to force that folder being created in git in [this commit](https://github.com/NetCoreApps/CreatorKit/commit/eb56ac04896f7278707ec2176d6262ec8c589863).

If you include the same file it will be included when the GitHub Actions task pulls down the repo.

Comment: It turned out the EmailRenderer.SaveMailingListEnum(...) command in Migration1001.cs had a hard coded path for the savePath that Docker / GithubActions did not like. 
The resulting MailingList.cs enum file already did exist in the solution, so for the time being I have commented that line out.

The line is near line 174 of CreatorKit/Migrations/Migration1001.cs